# Sharing memory from kernel to user space by disabling the "Write Protect Bit (CR0:16)"

Tags: linux, memory, module, kernel

If I have my own kernel space memory manager, is it theoretically possible to share a memory pointer allocated by a kernel module to a user space application by disabling the "Write Protect Bit (CR0:16)" using read_cr0() and write_cr0() thus allowing read/write access to the entire system memory space?

(This is for embedded devices where we "trust" our own processes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just experimented on my own computer but to answer my own question: NO, it is not possible to share the kernel's memory directly with a user space process.

I did try to write my own kernel module based on Tempesta's stack-like region-based memory manager ([pool.c](https://github.com/tempesta-tech/tempesta/blob/master/tempesta_fw/pool.c)):

```
[...]

static int __init
tfw_pool_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "HIJACK INIT\n");
    write_cr0 (read_cr0 () & (~ 0x10000));

    pg_cache = alloc_percpu(unsigned long [TFW_POOL_PGCACHE_SZ]);
    if (pg_cache == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;

    printk(KERN_NOTICE "__tfw_pool_new = %p\n", __tfw_pool_new);
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "tfw_pool_alloc = %p\n", tfw_pool_alloc);
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "tfw_pool_realloc = %p\n", tfw_pool_realloc);
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "tfw_pool_free = %p\n", tfw_pool_free);
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "tfw_pool_destroy = %p\n", tfw_pool_destroy);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit
tfw_pool_exit(void)
{
    free_percpu(pg_cache);

    write_cr0 (read_cr0 () | 0x10000);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "MODULE EXIT\n");
}

module_init(tfw_pool_init);
module_exit(tfw_pool_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

And not only calling the functions printed out segfaults but my system became highly unstable after loading the module so **DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME**.